# I do not want the Android notification icon to be white

Tags: android, icons, android-notifications, notification-icons

I tested several Android Marshmallow devices.

There are some devices that display white icons, others do not.

I want to consistently display images as .png files on all devices.

Is there a way?

Comment: White icons are recommend by the [android design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#style11). If the icons are another colour, then the developers are just 'ignoring' them. Not sure what you mean with `"display images as png files"`

Comment: @liquide I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "Hi"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333), and add the appropriate interpunction.